# How to split a value by separator?

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I am running advantage database 10.

One of my field databases Has "customer name" and it is stored as "Lastname, FirstName".  I want to be able to extract the first name out of the the field.  I figured this would work, but no dice:

```
SELECT   [Customer Name]
        ,LEFT([Customer Name], CHARINDEX(',', [Customer Name]) - 1) AS [Surname]
        ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Customer Name], CHARINDEX(',', [Customer Name]), LEN([FullName])), ',', '') AS [FirstName]
FROM    orders
```

I received no results. Here is the error message:

```
poQuery: Error 7200: AQE Error: State = S0000; NativeError = 2158; [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Scalar function not found: charindex -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 57 (line: 2 column: 32)
```

Basically I wouldneed
| CUSTOMER NAME |
     Doe, John

to become:
|FIRST NAME| LAST NAME |
 John      |  Doe

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read and follow [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/1920232) if you want to get any help and not have your question downvoted or closed

Comment: Ok, so what does "no dice" mean? What is the actual behavior that you see? Do you get an error message or unexpected results? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry!  I meant I received no results.  Here is the error message:
**poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2158;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Scalar function not found: charindex -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 57 (line: 2 column: 32)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `POSITION(',' IN field)` syntax.

See the documentation here:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage12/master_string_functions.htm

Your query would look something like this (untested):

```
SELECT   [Customer Name]
        ,LEFT([Customer Name], POSITION(',' IN [Customer Name]) - 1) AS [Surname]
        ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Customer Name], POSITION(',' IN [Customer Name]), LENGTH([FullName])), ',', '') AS [FirstName]
FROM    orders
```

Comment: Thanks Jens!  I'm not quite sure how to format that in the SQL view.  
How would you suggest formatting it?  I tried to insert POSITION in place of CHARINDEX.

Comment: Thank you very much!  There was a slight change needed.  LEN had to be changed to LENGTH.  Other than that-- it's splitting exactly as I was looking for.  Thank you!  

Here is the updated code:
'
SELECT   [Customer Name]
        ,LEFT([Customer Name], POSITION(',' IN [Customer Name]) - 1) AS [Surname]
        ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Customer Name], POSITION(',' IN [Customer Name]), LENGTH([Customer Name])), ',', '') AS [FirstName]
FROM    orders
'